# UserManager<User> does not find a existing user in database asp.net core Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-2.1, asp.net-core-identity

I have ASP.NET Core 2.1 MVC Application. Also in database I have 1 user in role "Admin",but when I try to get list of users in database it returns an empty list.It normaly returns data from "Roles" and "UserRoles" tables, but is unable to see any data in "Users" table and, consequently I can't use SignInAsync, or PasswordSignInAsync methods.
This is my dbContext:

```
public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User, Role, string>
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options):base(options)
    { }

    // ...
}
```

And here is my Startup:

```
services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
});

services.AddIdentity<User, Role>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

// ...
```

Comment: When you say it normally returns data, what exactly do you mean? Do you mean it used to return data, you changed something and now it no longer returns data?

Comment: please add what you expect to see and what are you currently getting and any errors.

Comment: @CodingYoshi It returns data from "Roles" and "UserRoles" table , but It is unable to retrieve any user from "Users" table

Comment: @BlooB it does't throw any errors,I expect to get a List<User> with 1 element, but it returns a list with 0 elements.

Comment: How do you know it is unable to retrieve any user from the user table? Where is the code for retrieval?

Comment: @CodingYoshi var users =  await _usermanager.Users.ToList(); List contains 0 elements, although there is 1 user in AspNetUsers table

Comment: `UserManager<TUser>` has no `Users` member. Looks like you've customized something somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to have NORMALIZEDUSERNAME and NORMALIZEDEMAIL with the same value on email and username in uppercase.

Comment: This is what I forgot after manually seeding an identity user. Silly Identity Framework.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that was happening to me was the following:

I was inserting the user directly through the Entity User, and not by CreateAsync in UserManager method.

This was bypassing any routine that computes PasswordHash, SecurityStamp and other fields in database, so PasswordSignInAsync wasn't working due to this.